# What's the Fourier transform of the p-Laplacian operator $\Delta_{p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider the p-Laplacian operator $\Delta_{p}u:= div(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)$, where $1<p<\infty$. We know when $p=2$, it's the standard laplacian operator. So my question is what is the fourier transform of this operator.
For general Laplacian, I know $\widehat {\Delta u}(\xi)=|\xi|^2 \hat u(\xi)$. What is $\widehat {\Delta_{p} u}(\xi)$?

I couldn't find relevant notes and only find this link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228009/backgrounds-of-the-p-laplacian-operator

Comment: I think you may have trouble writing down a simple expression. You can use simple properties of the Fourier transform to get to the point where you have a convolution of two Fourier transformed functions weighed by the symbol from the divergence. Beyond that, you have to understand the Fourier transform of $$|\nabla u|^{p-2}$$. And since the Fourier transform doesn’t play nice with the absolute value, you could be out of luck.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that for certain values of p, one can write down a relatively simple expression. For p = 4, you get three convolutions of Fourier transforms of u weighed by symbols coming from the corresponding derivatives.

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o Thanks. Then, it seems we can only find an explicit expression when $p=n/2$, where $n$ is an even number.